# Does the Surface Pro 3 support sending audio through the mini-DisplayPort connector?

Tags: audio, windows-8.1, mini-displayport, microsoft-surface-pro

I have a Surface Pro 3 that I'm trying to connect to a TV via a mini-DisplayPort to HDMI cable, but I'm not getting sound. Does the Surface Pro 3 support this?

I found information via Google that the Surface Pro and Surface Pro 2 do support it, but nothing definitive on the Surface Pro 3.

Comment: Of course it does because display port does but you have to use a display port cable that supports it

Comment: @Ramhound Even if the connector supports it, not all video adpaters support routing the audio through the video card

Comment: The Intel GPU inside it supports it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the Surface Pro 3 does support this. However, not all cables will carry the signal. I swapped the cable I was using for a different one, and it worked just fine.